# set a return value to a class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following method and i am trying to get data from a column called `ApptDateTime` and set it to a public class so that i can pass the value into another method.

This is what i was trying to set the value in the public class:

```
public class ApptData
{
    public DateTime _currentAppointment { get; set; }
}
```

I select the value `_currentAppointment` and i want to be able to call it from `public class ApptData` And then pass that into a Method.

EX: `history.LoadHistory(ApptData appointment, daysOfHistory);`

```
    private void dgvPendingSB_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.AddedItems[0];

            int accNum = -1;
            int resourceId = Convert.ToInt32(row["ResourceId"]);
            int locationId = Convert.ToInt32(row["LocationId"]);
            int patientId = Convert.ToInt32(row["PatientId"]);
            _currentAppointment = Convert.ToDateTime(row["ApptDate"]);
            m_objPatient = Convert.ToInt32(row["PatientId"]);
            _stringPatientName = row["PatientName"].ToString();
            // ...
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you are experiencing?

Comment: I am confused by your statement of "I select the value '_currentAppointment' and I want to be able to call it from 'public class ApptData'.". You are storing the row data into an instance of the ApptData class, but you are not instantiating an instance of that class. Your code posted should not work for `_currentAppointment = ...`, because a property cannot just float around without being attached to an object.

Comment: Public properties should be cased like `CurrentAppointment`, not like `_currentAppointment`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to pass a *new instance* of `ApptData` into `LoadHistory` with a value from your `DataRowView` set, you'll want something like:

```
history.LoadHistory(new ApptData()
   {
      _currentAppointment = Convert.ToDateTime(row["ApptDate"])
   }, daysOfHistory);
```

Also, I strongly recommend you *don't* start `public` properties, fields or methods with an underscore.  It's just *weird*.

Comment: Agreed, underscores should be for member variables only, but certainly not for object properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate an instance of `ApptData`, set the value for `__currentAppointment` and then pass that to the `LoadHistory` method, like this:

```
var theAppointmentData = new ApptData();
theAppointmentData._currentAppointment = Convert.ToDateTime(row["ApptDate"]);
```

Then you can call your `LoadHistory` method, like this:

```
history.LoadHistory(theAppointmentData, daysOfHistory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understand you question. Do you want to use the class itself instead of an instance (is that what you mean by "public class?")? If so... You could use a default object to carry your property:

```
public class ApptData
{
    private static ApptData _defaultInstance;

    public static ApptData Default
    {
        if (_defaultInstance == null)
        {
             _defaultInstance = new ApptData();
        }
        return _defaultInstance;
    }

    public DateTime CurrentAppointment { get; set; }
}
```

You can access the property like this:

```
    ApptData.Default.CurrentAppointment = Convert.ToDateTime(row["ApptDate"]);
    history.LoadHistory(ApptData.Default, daysOfHistory);
```

But to me that is a very awkward way of passing data. The only use this could serve is that you can access the value of that property from anywhere that ApptData class is visible. Of course, you could only process one value at a time. I would do what the previous readers suggested and have everything as instantiated objects.